# Query FireStore against a List of Documents

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, task

I have a `List<String>` of names referring to Documents that I want to retrieve from FireStore. I want to access the contents after they are finished loading so I have implemented an `OnCompleteListener` in the `Fragment` that uses the data. However, I am not sure how to run a loop within a `Task` to query FireStore for each Document. I am querying FireStore in a Repository class that returns a `Task` object back through my `ViewModel` and finally to my `Fragment`. I want the Repository to return a `Task` so that I can attach an `OnCompleteListener` to it in order to know when I have finished loading my data.

My Repository `Query` method:

```
public Task<List<GroupBase>> getGroups(List<String> myGroupTags){
    final List<GroupBase> myGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String groupTag : myGroupTags){
        groupCollection.document(groupTag).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            myGroups.add(task.getResult().toObject(GroupBase.class));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    return null; //Ignore this for now.
}
```

I know this won't return what I need but I am not sure how to structure a `Task` that incorporates a loop inside of it. Would I need to extract the contents of the `List<String>` in my `Fragment` and run individual queries for each item?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what do you actually need, to transform a list of string into a list of Tasks?

Comment: It will be easier if you collect a bunch of Task objects and wait for them all to complete with Tasks.whenAll() to get a single Task with all the results.

Comment: @AlexMamo essentially yes. I have a List of Document names and I need to transform this to essentially a List of Tasks to retrieve the entire document. Hi Doug, so you're suggesting I iterate through the list and for each item construct a Task and append the individual task to a new list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> I have a List of Document names and I need to transform this to essentially a List of Tasks to retrieve the entire document.

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference collRef = rootRef.collection("yourCollection");
List<String> myGroupTags = new ArrayList<>();
List<DocumentReference> listDocRef = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s : myGroupTags) {
    DocumentReference docRef = collRef.document(s);
    listDocRef.add(docRef);
}

List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (DocumentReference documentReference : listDocRef) {
    Task<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotTask = documentReference.get();
    tasks.add(documentSnapshotTask);
}
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
        //Do what you need to do with your list
        for (Object object : list) {
            GroupBase gb = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(GroupBase.class);
            Log.d("TAG", tp.getPropertyname);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does initializing Task execute it? I don't kow why, but I feel like the get() method just executes it no matter what. Is this the case?

Comment: @JakubKostka I'm afraid I did not understand you but please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.