# What adapter can I use to populate a recyclerView that accepts multiple queries from Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

This question grew out of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860624/can-a-query-be-constructed-using-a-list-of-strings-that-represent-a-field-in-a-f). I am looking for an adapter to populate my `RecyclerView` with multiple queries.

I am currently using the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` but was informed that since it only accepts a single query I cannot use it to populate a `RecyclerView` with selected documents in a collection.

What I currently have:

```
Query posts = db.collection("posts");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                .setQuery(posts, Post.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder postViewHolder, int position, @NonNull Post post) {
                postViewHolder.setPost(post);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: FireStore DataBase]

This currently retrieves all posts in my posts collection however I want to use a list to filter for only posts that contain userId's in said list. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doug Stevenson mentioned in his answer:

> You will have to make a query for each one of the documents you want to display, collect the results in memory, and use a different type of adapter to populate the view.

As I see in your code, you are still using a single query, which in your code is named `posts`. For example, if you want to get documents from within two queries, two query objects are required. In code, this is how you can merge two queries locally:

- [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally)

As you can see, the `onSuccess()` method has as an argument, a `List<Object>`, which basically contains the result of both queries.

> I am looking for an adapter to populate my recycler view with multiple queries.

And to answer your question, since you want to display the data in a `RecyclerView`, the most appropriate type of adapter that might be is a `RecyclerView.Adapter` and **not** `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` which doesn't accept a list. Pass that list to the adapter's constructor and display each element in its own `ViewHolder`. That's it!

Comment: What if I don't know how many queries I will need to make? The list I want to make queries of is not of a set length.

Comment: Also why can't FirestoreRecyclerAdapter accept a list of queries if it extends RecyclerView.Adapter?

Comment: You should know since you get the number from the database. If you have more than two queries, you can use a `List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>>` as in my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892766/android-firestore-convert-array-of-document-references-to-listpojo/51897261)**. So you can pass a list of tasks to the `whenAllSuccess()`. There can be two (as in my example), there or as many as you want.

Comment: First of all you aren't passing to the `RecyclerView.Adapter` a list of queries, you are passing a list of objects that is coming from the database. You cannot pass any list to the [FirestoreRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java) constructor because none of its constructors allow you to lass a list. You are allowed only to pass a `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` object, right?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, if you would help me I would be very grateful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68006079/java-android-use-listadapter-to-show-posts-of-followed-users

Comment: @pophome I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.